# Getting Contradicting results with the Fundamental Theorem of Complex integrals and Cauchy's integral theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

The way I prove the fundemental theorem of complex integrals is as follows:

$$\int_\gamma f'(z)dz = \int_a^b f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt = \int_a^b g'(t)dt = g(b)-g(a)=f(z_2)-f(z_1)$$

Where in the first equality, I parametrized using the variable $t$, and in the second equality, I defined a new function $g(t) \equiv f(\gamma(t))$, so $g'(t)=f'(\gamma)\gamma'(t)$.

The thing is, the path can be defined however I want. So I can define a path that can around a pole ($\gamma_1$), and another that takes a straight line ($\gamma_2$) and get the same result. This gives a contradiction:

$$\int_{\gamma_1} f'(z)dz = \int_{\gamma_2}f'(z)dz$$

$$\int_{\gamma_1}f'(z)dz - \int_{\gamma_2} f'(z)dz = 0 \implies \oint f'(z) dz=0$$

Even though the path encircles a pole. was is the mistake I made?

What I thought of is that the problem was in taking the derivative $f'(z)$ even though there is a pole. It's not possible because it is no longer holomorphic. The thing is, given a circle centered at the pole such that the function $f'(z)$ is holomorphic outside of it, then wouldn't that get around the problem? So what is the mistake?

Comment: There is no mistake. Integrating the *derivative* of a holomorphic function over a closed path gives always zero.

Comment: Isn't any function a derivative of another?

Comment: @MartinR I think I go it. I reasoned that if the function has a simple pole, then its antiderivative would be a function that requires a riemann surface to work. eg: 1/z, ln(z), but how can I show that formally?

Comment: @Habouz "Isn't any function a derivative of another?" It needs to be the derivative of something _holomorphic_.